# Destroying widgets in Dijit

Tags: javascript, dojo

What's the correct way to destroy widgets inside `TabContainer` in **Dojo/Dijit**?

For each tab I'm loading new `BorderContainer` that includes basically a widget that includes any small widgets. But now that I'm trying to get it to work with tab control so that it destroys the previous page before loading a new one, I'm stuck. Right now I use a global variable to store active widget name and when user clicks a new tab, it fetches active widget's id from global variable and destroys it and then proceeds into loading the new active widget. This works but when I have destroyed the widget once, I can't get it to appear again. I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Tried to register widget with id==widget_foo_container but that id is already registered".

I'm using `widget_XXX_container` id for all the widgets so `XXX` is replaced by id of the widget.

I'm currently using d`ijit.byId('widget_foo_container').destroy()` but it doesn't seem to do the job. I have also tried `destroyDecendant()` and `destroyRecursive()` but they don't produce wanted effect also. It seems that I might be missing a piece that actually finishes destroying the widget instead of just removing it from DOM.

Comment: I actually got this to work. What I needed to do was to getChildren() from BorderContainer and then with forEach() destroyRecursive() & destroy()... pheew, that was frustrating 3 hours...

Comment: `destroyRecursive` should be enough - it calls `destroyDescendants` and `destroy` itself.  For that matter, I'm curious why simply calling `destroyRecursive` on the BorderContainer itself didn't suffice in your case...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at dijit.registry to see if your widgets are still registered...

Example :

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="btn1" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button">Button1</div>
        <div id="btn2" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button">Destroy button 1
            <script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onClick">
                dijit.byId("btn1") && dijit.byId("btn1").destroyRecursive();
                console.debug(dijit.registry._hash);
            </script>
        </div>
        <div id="btn3" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button">Recreate button 1
            <script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onClick">
                dojo.place(new dijit.form.Button({ label: "Button1", id:"btn1"}).domNode, "wrapper", "first");
                console.debug(dijit.registry._hash);
            </script>
        </div>
</div>
```